# Consequences of non-comoving inertial frames in free fall

Tags: general-relativity

Suppose we have a space ship on a highly eccentric orbit that passes by the International Space Station at its point of lowest approach.

Now we have an inertial frame on the ISS that is accelerating dramatically with respect to another inertial frame on the space ship, and vice versa.

What are some of the consequences of this? If we charge up the space ship, does the ISS see it radiate? Do the ISS and the space ship disagree about each others' proper times? Any articles that approach related questions in a relatively accessible manner? Sorry the question is kind of vague...

Comment: If you are asking whether a charge falling in a gravitational field radiates that has been discussed before in lots of questions. For the gory details see [Paradox of radiation of charged particles in a gravitational field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_radiation_of_charged_particles_in_a_gravitational_field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now we have an inertial frame on the ISS that is accelerating dramatically with respect to another inertial frame on the space ship, and vice versa.

In GR it is important to distinguish between two types of acceleration: proper acceleration and coordinate acceleration. Proper acceleration is a relativistic invariant, all frames agree on its value. Proper acceleration is a physical quantity with physically measurable consequences. Coordinate acceleration is an artifact of the coordinates and different coordinates will disagree. Importantly, coordinate acceleration has no measurable consequences at all.

> What are some of the consequences of this? If we charge up the space ship, does the ISS see it radiate? Do the ISS and the space ship disagree about each others' proper times? Any articles that approach related questions in a relatively accessible manner?

There are no physical consequences of this whatsoever.

If you mean proper acceleration then both agree that the other is moving inertially and that they are undergoing no proper acceleration. They both agree about all relativistic invariants such as proper times.

If you mean coordinate acceleration then there are again no physical consequences simply because coordinate acceleration itself is non-physical. Coordinate acceleration has no experimentally measurable consequences.

Now, there are physical consequences of the curvature of spacetime and their different paths through it. But because the laws of physics are covariant, both will agree on the outcome of all physical experiments. Specifically, if one craft, being charged, predicts that some antenna will detect radiation, then so will the other.